# Wordpress function makes my menu disappear

Tags: php, wordpress, function, custom-post-type

I am using this function to make my custom post type "portfolio" show up on archives/category/tag pages (in functions.php):

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
  if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'portfolio'));
      return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types'
```

The problem is that for some reason it is making my nav menu disappear.  Here is the code for the nav menu (in header.php):

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'theme_location'  => 'primary', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'container_class' => 'nav-menu',) ); ?>
```

Any idea what I can change?

Comment: Do you have any error in console ?

Comment: Is the html of the menu present in the code ?

Comment: All of the html from the menu just comes from wp_nav_menu(), it is then styled by css. No html is being outputted though.  If I remove the function "namespace_add_custom_types" then the menu returns to working.

Comment: try commenting out the line:

    return $query;

Does that make the menu re-appear?

Comment: No, it seems like it is just the line above that that is doing it.

Answer (score 9):

WordPress nav menus consist of posts of the `nav_menu_item` post type, and as your function changes the post type for all queries, there is nothing to display.

Solution: modify only the main query by checking [`is_main_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query), e.g.:

```
if( is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

PS: `pre_get_posts` is an **action** hook, so you should use `add_action` instead of `add_filter`:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this: `'nav_menu_item'` to the array in your functions.php file.
Final code looks like this:

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
   if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
      $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'nav_menu_item', 'portfolio'));
      return $query;
   }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```